# Find all values $m$ and $n$ for which the graph $Gm,n$ is connected.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $Gn,m$ be a graph with $n$ vertices, where any 2 vertices $i$ and $j$ are adjacent only if $| i - j | > m$, where $m> 0$.
Find all values $m$ and $n$ for which the graph $Gm,n$ is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
The graph $G_{n,m}$ is connected if and only if $m\leq[\frac{n}{2}]-1$.

Proof.
Consider the case where $n$ is even. Let $n=2k$ and $m\leq k-1$.
Then, since $k+i-1>k-1\geq m$ for all $i =1,\ldots,k$,
vertex 1 is adjacent to vertices $k+1,\ldots,2k=n$.
Similarly, $j$ is adjacent to $k+j,\ldots,2k$ for all $j=2,\ldots,2k=n$.
We will write $i\sim j$ if $i$ is adjacent to $j$.
We have
$$
k+1\sim1\sim k+2\sim2\sim k+3\sim3\sim\ldots\sim k+k\sim k.
$$
Thus we have proved that if $m\leq k-1$, then the graph $G_{m,n}$ is connected.

If $m\geq k$, then the vertex $k$ is not adjacent to any vertex of the graph since $|k-i|\leq k\leq m$
for any vertex $i=1,\ldots,2k$.
Thus $i$ is an isolated vertex of $G_{m,n}$
and we have proved that if $m\geq k$, then the graph $G_{m,n}$ is not connected.

The proof in the case when $n$ is odd is similar.

Comment: In what way is this a hint?

Comment: It is a statement that needs to be proved.
I would not want to deprive the author of the question of the pleasure of getting the proof on his own. Especially since it is very simple.

Comment: Given that the author put nothing in their question but the homework assignment they were given, I doubt they can appreciate the pleasure of getting the proof on their own, and for that matter might not even be looking for the proof.

Comment: It is impossible to disagree with it. 
One can only pity the author of the question. The problem is a beautiful one.

Comment: @kabenyuk The answer is at the end of the book of mathematical problems, but I need to prove it, but I do not know how, please tell me the algorithm for solving this problem.

Comment: @Archangel_00000 I I added a proof.